# R starts_with error in filter_at (`starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function.)

Tags: r, dplyr

With a dataset similar to this:

```
id <- c("john","paul","george","ringo","mick","dozy","beaky","tich")
allow_a <- c("Y","N","Y","Y","","","Y","")
allow_b <- c("N","","N","","N","N","N","Y")
generic_a <- c("N","","","Y","Y","Y","N","")
generic_b <- c("N","","","N","Y","N","","Y")

df <- data.frame(id, allow_a, allow_b, generic_a, generic_b)
```

If I run something with a `starts_with` function:

```
df %>%
select(starts_with("all"))
```

It works fine and selects the correct columns. However, if i try:

```
filter_at(df,
          vars(starts_with("all")),
          any_vars(. == "Y"))
```

I get the error `` Error: `starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function. ``
If i use `rlang::last_error()` to trace the error I get:

```
Backtrace:
  1. dplyr::filter_at(...)
 11. tidyselect::starts_with("all")
 13. tidyselect::peek_vars(fn = "starts_with")
```

I guess this is an issue with the installed packages, but not really sure how to fix it. Package versions are:

```
dplyr_0.8.4
tidyselect_1.0.0
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: where is `id`?.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (`dplyr` version 0.8.4).  Works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on but after some testing today it's a conflict with the `expss` package. I'm not sure why `starts_with` is singled out here but `contains` is mentioned when loading `expss` into library:

```
Loading required package: expss

Attaching package: ‘expss’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:tidyr’:

    contains, nest

The following objects are masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    copy, like

The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    between, compute, contains, first, last, na_if, recode, vars
```

Not sure how to trace the error back but this may be useful if other users experience the same error...

Comment: I haven't properly solved it, but loading the `expss` package before `tidyverse` or `dplyr` removed the error for me.

Comment: It does seem to be due to a conflict with other packages. In my case, I think `sets` masked some features out. Restarting the session and loading dplyr as the last package solved it.